# When Using Order By Clause the Execution time is 40 Times high

Tags: mysql, indexing

I have a table with 200,000 records that I'm trying to filter and sort with some conditions.

- *Without* `ORDER BY p.date_time desc`, the query takes 0.078 seconds.
- With `ORDER BY p.date_time desc` it takes 2.225 seconds

**Query:**

```
SELECT p.*
        , s.*
        ,  (SELECT  COUNT(1)
            FROM    gbs_comments
            WHERE   product_short_url = p.product_short_url 
        ) AS comment_count
        ,( EXISTS
            ( SELECT *
              FROM  `gbs_likes`
              WHERE `product_short_url` = p.product_short_url
              AND `ip_address` = '1' 
             )
        ) AS like_status
FROM   gbs_products p, gbs_store s
WHERE  p.deal_type = 1
  AND  p.product_store = s.sid
ORDER BY p.date_time DESC
```

**Table Indexes:**

[image: Screenshot of table indexes]

Explain Plan:

[image: Explain Plan]

Table Indexes:

GBS_COMMENTS

[image: GBS_COMMENTS INDEX]

GBS_LIKES INDEX

[image: GBS_LIKES]

GBS PRODUCT INDEX

[image: GBS_PRODUCT]

Comment: Can you show the `EXPLAIN` output for both queries?

Comment: Please [use text, not images/links, for text--including tables & ERDs.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097) Paraphrase or quote from other text. Use images only for what cannot be expressed as text or to augment text. Images cannot be searched for or cut & pasted. Include a legend/key & explanation with an image. Make your post self-contained. Please before you post look at the formatted version of your post below the edit box. Read the edit help.

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mcve]--cut & paste & runnable code; example input with desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & clear specification & explanation. For SQL that includes DBMS/product & DDL which includes constraints & indexes. For SQL performance that includes EXPLAIN results. (Constraints, indexes & plans are critical to performance.) PS What did your research show are the few most important factors to query performance & what is most helpful in a question about it? PS What is the most likely thing adding an ORDER BY is gong to cause?

Comment: Please before you post look at the formatted version of your post below the edit box. Read the edit help re inline & block formats for code & quotations.

Comment: Which table has those indexes?  What about the other tables?  Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for each table, there could be subtle things, such as `COLLATION`, that are causing trouble.

Answer (score 0):

`gbs_comments` needs `INDEX(product_short_url)`

`gbs_likes` needs `INDEX(ip_address, product_short_url)`, in either order.

`gbs_products` needs `INDEX(deal_type, date_time)`, in *this* order.

Comment: Hi Rick see without the orderby the query executes very faster... only with orderby query takes time

Comment: @Magesh - The `EXPLAIN` you provided is for the `ORDER BY` version?  Please provide the non-order-by version.  It is curious that it started with `s`.  What are the datatypes of `p.product_store` and `s.sid`?

Comment: @Magesh - Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for _all 4_ tables.

Comment: Hi Rick !! as you said its correct .. i created index of store sid then the query was quick  for 1lakh table record , but when it takes longer time for more than 1.5 lakh data record... any suggestions...

Comment: How much RAM?  What is the value of `innodb_buffer_pool_size`?  Are you using InnoDB?  Which table has 150K rows?